# build\generated\libs does not exist when compiling my titanium android module

Tags: android, ant, module

I am trying to compile my titanium android module with ant,but the error comes like build\generated\libs does not exist,if i created manually it compiled but it is not worked well,i found in this forum only this process is not correct,so please any one help me out.

```
C:\Users\ensis\Documents\Titaniumstudioworkspace\sip6>ant
Buildfile: C:\Users\ensis\Documents\Titaniumstudioworkspace\sip6\build.xml

init:

process.annotations:

generate.rhino.bindings:
     [java] Generating C:\Users\ensis\Documents\Titaniumstudioworkspace\sip6\bui
ld\generated\java\com\yydigital\sipclient\SipclientProxyPrototype.java
     [java] Generating C:\Users\ensis\Documents\Titaniumstudioworkspace\sip6\bui
ld\generated\java\com\yydigital\sipclient\SipclientModulePrototype.java
     [java] Generating C:\Users\ensis\Documents\Titaniumstudioworkspace\sip6\bui
ld\generated\java\sip6GeneratedBindings.java

generate.rhino.idswitch:
     [echo] Generating IDs for C:\Users\ensis\Documents\Titaniumstudioworkspace\
sip6\build\generated\java\com\yydigital\sipclient\SipclientBootstrap.java
     [echo] Generating IDs for C:\Users\ensis\Documents\Titaniumstudioworkspace\
sip6\build\generated\java\com\yydigital\sipclient\SipclientModulePrototype.java
     [echo] Generating IDs for C:\Users\ensis\Documents\Titaniumstudioworkspace\
sip6\build\generated\java\com\yydigital\sipclient\SipclientProxyPrototype.java
     [echo] Generating IDs for C:\Users\ensis\Documents\Titaniumstudioworkspace\
sip6\build\generated\java\sip6GeneratedBindings.java

generate.v8.bindings:
     [java] Generating C:\Users\ensis\Documents\Titaniumstudioworkspace\sip6\bui
ld\generated\jni\com.yydigital.sipclient.SipclientProxy.h
     [java] Generating C:\Users\ensis\Documents\Titaniumstudioworkspace\sip6\bui
ld\generated\jni\com.yydigital.sipclient.SipclientProxy.cpp
     [java] Generating C:\Users\ensis\Documents\Titaniumstudioworkspace\sip6\bui
ld\generated\jni\com.yydigital.sipclient.SipclientModule.h
     [java] Generating C:\Users\ensis\Documents\Titaniumstudioworkspace\sip6\bui
ld\generated\jni\com.yydigital.sipclient.SipclientModule.cpp
     [exec] Traceback (most recent call last):
     [exec]   File "C:\Users\ensis\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\2.1.
4.GA\module\android\bootstrap.py", line 395, in <module>
     [exec]     main()
     [exec]   File "C:\Users\ensis\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\2.1.
4.GA\module\android\bootstrap.py", line 363, in main
     [exec]     from manifest import Manifest
     [exec]   File "C:\Users\ensis\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\2.1.
4.GA\manifest.py", line 4, in <module>
     [exec]     from StringIO import StringIO
     [exec] ImportError: No module named 'StringIO'

generate.bindings:

pre.compile:
     [exec]   File "C:\Users\ensis\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\2.1.
4.GA\module\android\android.py", line 25
     [exec]     print "[ERROR] Couldn't find the Android API r%s platform direct
ory" % androidsdk.DEFAULT_API_LEVEL
     [exec]
   ^
     [exec] SyntaxError: invalid syntax

js.compile:

ndk.build:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\ensis\AppData\Local\Temp\ensis\sip6-generated
     [copy] Copying 15 files to C:\Users\ensis\AppData\Local\Temp\ensis\sip6-gen
erated
     [exec] jni/Android.mk:24: warning: overriding commands for target `C:/Users
/ensis/AppData/Local/Temp/ensis/sip6-generated/KrollGeneratedBindings.cpp'
     [exec] jni/Android.mk:24: warning: ignoring old commands for target `C:/Use
rs/ensis/AppData/Local/Temp/ensis/sip6-generated/KrollGeneratedBindings.cpp'
     [exec] jni/Android.mk:27: warning: overriding commands for target `C:/Users
/ensis/AppData/Local/Temp/ensis/sip6-generated/BootstrapJS.cpp'
     [exec] jni/Android.mk:27: warning: ignoring old commands for target `C:/Use
rs/ensis/AppData/Local/Temp/ensis/sip6-generated/BootstrapJS.cpp'
     [exec] jni/Android.mk:24: warning: overriding commands for target `C:/Users
/ensis/AppData/Local/Temp/ensis/sip6-generated/KrollGeneratedBindings.cpp'
     [exec] jni/Android.mk:24: warning: ignoring old commands for target `C:/Use
rs/ensis/AppData/Local/Temp/ensis/sip6-generated/KrollGeneratedBindings.cpp'
     [exec] jni/Android.mk:27: warning: overriding commands for target `C:/Users
/ensis/AppData/Local/Temp/ensis/sip6-generated/BootstrapJS.cpp'
     [exec] jni/Android.mk:27: warning: ignoring old commands for target `C:/Use
rs/ensis/AppData/Local/Temp/ensis/sip6-generated/BootstrapJS.cpp'
     [exec] "Compile++ thumb : com.yydigital.sipclient <= com.yydigital.sipclien
t.SipclientModule.cpp
     [exec] In file included from jni/com.yydigital.sipclient.SipclientModule.cp
p:23:
     [exec] jni/com.yydigital.sipclient.SipclientProxy.h:36: error: expected unq
ualified-id before 'const'
     [exec] jni/com.yydigital.sipclient.SipclientProxy.h:36: error: expected ')'
 before 'const'
     [exec] make: *** [C:\Users\ensis\AppData\Local\Temp\/ensis/sip6-generated/o
bj/local/armeabi/objs/com.yydigital.sipclient/com.yydigital.sipclient.SipclientM
odule.o] Error 1
     [move] Moving 15 files to C:\Users\ensis\Documents\Titaniumstudioworkspace\
sip6\build\generated

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\ensis\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\2.1.4.GA\module\android\
build.xml:364: C:\Users\ensis\Documents\Titaniumstudioworkspace\sip6\build\gener
ated\libs does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

create folder libs in  C:\Users\ensis\Documents\Titaniumstudioworkspace\sip6\build\gener
ated\ refresh project and run ant.

(bad english :D )

Saludos.